# Learning Or Getting Ideas From Some Code Under Creative Commons Without Attributing the User?

Tags: discussion, legal, attribution, licensing, creative-commons

Let's say I was searching for how to hide the Console Window from a Win32 App and someone on Stack Overflow said something about FreeConsole() function or anything else so I went and checked the MSDN for it and learned about and how to use it.

Since Stack Exchange answers are under CC-BY-SA, do I have to release my code under CC and link to the user? Didn't use any of his code but he gave me the idea about the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Ideas" are free, and if the concept you made up, is based on things you have seen, no problem, just implement it the way you want.

If you directly copy/paste the content (or an adapted version of it, in any way) you need to use the correct attribution. See the [Creative Commons license](http://creativecommons.org/licenses/by-sa/3.0/), which is quite clear in my opinion about this.

Answer (score 4):

Copyright law does not protect [*ideas*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Idea%E2%80%93expression_divide), in and of themselves. It protects the *expression* of ideas. So if you get an *idea* from a piece of code that is CC-BY-SA but not the *expression* of this idea, copyright does not compel you to give attribution.

This is not the end of the story, however. Let's say the idea is extremely original, and your implementation of it looks like the original implementation, it is unlikely that a court would find that the resemblance is indeed mere happenstance. If the idea is a commonplace one, you'd have a better chance. This is why, to prevent leaving things to chance, companies that are engaging in reverse-engineering use [clean room design](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Clean_room_design).